# Atom editor don't shows interface in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: atom-editor

I was working with atom, and everything was nice, but ubuntu showed me a message about an upgrade according to my hardware settings, I installed it and after that, atom stopped working, it opens but I can't see nothing, the screen is black, I reinstalled atom and the same problem continues.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your graphics drivers. I've noticed similar behavior once when updating my nvidia drivers. I had to purge the drivers and install the previous stable release to fix this issue. Perhaps this will help.

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani Oh, I'm going to try that, thank you.

Comment: Let me know if it works @elG